# Xcode 9 WebKit Not Loading Outside Pages

Tags: ios, xcode

I am using this code here on my app to load a website however it does not allow me to open outside links within my website. For example, if you click on facebook, it does not do anything. Any suggestions?

```
import UIKit
import WebKit
class ViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate {
@IBOutlet weak var webViewContainer: UIView!
var webView: WKWebView!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    let customFrame = CGRect.init(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: CGSize.init(width: 0.0, height: self.webViewContainer.frame.size.height))
    self.webView = WKWebView (frame: customFrame , configuration: webConfiguration)
    webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.webViewContainer.addSubview(webView)
    webView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: webViewContainer.topAnchor).isActive = true
    webView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: webViewContainer.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    webView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: webViewContainer.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    webView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: webViewContainer.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    webView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: webViewContainer.heightAnchor).isActive = true
    webView.uiDelegate = self

    let myURL = URL(string: "https://gracekutztown.weebly.com")
    let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
    webView.load(myRequest)
  }
}
```

Comment: My memory is fuzzy, but take a close look at your console output and see if you have a warning about not being allowed to connect because of some kind of privacy setting...you may need a plist entry for something like HTTP protocol being allowed, or something like that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WKWebView won't open external links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34407276/wkwebview-wont-open-external-links)